# How to determine if my iPhone XS is Fast Charging?

Tags: iphone, charging

I recently got myself a USB Type C to Lighting Cable and a 30W USB Type C Adaptor(USB-PD). When I plug in the charger to my iPhone, I find my phone charging noticeably faster than normal but there doesn't seem to be any indication on the screen regarding the device being Fast Charged.

I read online about a "Double Ding" sounds when plugging in, but I don't think it seems to happen for my device.

I have a iPhone XS Max running latest version of iOS 12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s no on-screen indication of the charging speed on current iOS versions.

The only way to really know is to time the charging, or use external hardware for USB-PD debugging that can show you the actual watts.

Comment: On Android this can simply be done with an app. So, I guess, in theory, if one had a jailbroken iOS device, one could make a program that displayed charging rate?

Comment: @Revetahw Yep! That should be possible. Since you can read the information about the power delivery once Jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

You can hear a chime or your phone vibrate twice to indicate fast charging (these vibrations may be a few seconds apart, so be patient.)

Comment: Never noticed this happen. I have been fast charging for about 10 months now.